# Taking the max value of predict_proba for each row in a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, classification, data-science

I have issues using the `predict_proba` function. I have a multi-class classification problem and using a random forest classifier for it. I would like to print the data and corresponding predicted class + predicted probability of that class. First of all, I could manage to do it for 1 prediction.

The code for one sample

```
y_pred=pickle_model.predict(df_test)
y_pred_prob = pickle_model.predict_proba(df_test)
ix = y_pred_prob.argmax(1).item()
list = []
list.append(y_pred[iy])
list.append(f'{y_pred_prob[0,ix]:.2%}')
```

However, I have struggled when I had given a test data set consists of more than 1-row item.
I have tried the following function and applied it to df row by row. However, I could only get an array of probabilities. Couldn't figure out how to get max for each row. I used `argmax` like below when there was one row.

This is the code for multiple sample test data:

```
def get_predict_proba(row, model):
return model.predict_proba(row.values.reshape(1,-1))

df['predicted_category'] = pickle_model.predict(df)
df['confidence'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_predict_proba(row, pickle_model), axis=1)
```

This gives an output like this:

| Id | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | predicted_category | confidence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ### | ######## | ######## | category_name 1 | predict_proba array |
| ### | ######## | ######## | category_name 2 | predict_proba array |

The expected output would be like this:

| Id | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | predicted_category | confidence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ### | ######## | ######## | category_name 1 | prob value of category_name 1 |
| ### | ######## | ######## | category_name 2 | prob value of category_name 2 |

My second issue is the reliability of the `predict_proba` function on a random forest classifier with multiple classes. Does it really give the correct ratio? I have a data set that has an imbalance between classes. If it does not, is there a better option or a fix to this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue with editing the get_predict_proba function like this:

```
def get_predict_proba(row, model):
y_pred_prob=model.predict_proba(row.values.reshape(1,-1))
ix = y_pred_prob.argmax(1).item()
return (f'{y_pred_prob[0,ix]:.2%}')
```

I still need deeper information about predict_proba and how does it work on multiclass classifiers with imbalanced classes. Also if there is a more efficient way to solve this, I would be happy to see. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### First "predict_proba" of the predicted value

`predict_proba` returns and array with the probability of every class you have, as you said. For sure, the biggest value or max of this array will correspond to the class predicted. So and easy solution would be returning the **max value** of the `predict_proba` array:

```
def get_predict_proba(row, model):
return max(model.predict_proba(row.values.reshape(1,-1)))
```

### Second question "predict_proba" in unbalanced classes

As definition, `predict_proba` is *"The predicted class probabilities of an input sample are computed as the mean predicted class probabilities of the trees in the forest. The class probability of a single tree is the fraction of samples of the same class in a leaf"*.

This means that you are evaluating the prediction of every tree of your random forest, and obtaining a probability as a result. If your Random Forest is having a good behavior with unbalanced classes, then is a good approach.

To sump up, I will focus in obtaining a good Random Forest model, if it deals good with unbalanced classes, then the `predict_proba` will be representative. If the random forest is not good enough, you will have to use some techniques to solve problems of unbalanced classes (oversampling or under sampling for example).